# Как отключить подсказки при написании кода?

Tags: android-studio

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Как отключить подсказки при написании кода ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30659947/7059757

Comment: Хотел спросить зачем, из скрина всё стало понятно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отключить автоматические подсказки, в настройках галку снимите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь подсказки будут появляться только при нажатии <kbd>ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>space</kbd>.